# Writing to hard disk in linux kernel file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

How does the linux kernel file system write data to the physical hard disk i.e. the individual bytes and blocks to the disk sectors, cylinder? I am not able to find it in the kernel. Are there assembly instructions that it uses or is there some other method. For memory, one could use memcpy, but for the hard disk what is the complementary function?

My question applies only to the linux kernel source code, not to general C programming. I am not able to find the functions inside the kernel tree that accomplish this.

Would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to accomplish this from a terminal, or inside a C-program for example? You have not tagged this question as C, that's why i m asking. If you mean from terminal, look for the command "dd".

Comment: @sestus: The terminal and C programs would both be userspace, not kernel.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as *the* Linux kernel file system. Nor can you write individual bytes to disk. (It's block storage.) Instead, Linux has a layered architecture, with drivers such as SATA and ext3. Neither is really useful on its own, and studying one would therefore give you an incomplete picture.